# Make a gradle script global so it can be used in all the modules

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have this script that works fine if defined in each module, but If I want to either move it to the root build.gradle or put it in a separate file so it can be reused in all the modules is not working correctly.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId packageName
            version = libraryVersion
            artifactId project.getName()
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.getByName("_releaseCompile").getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It requires to define these variables in each module

```
def packageName = 'com.example.test'
def libraryVersion = '1.0'
```

So what happens if when I moved the script to make it global , it never finds these variables on each of the modules.

So I tried something like this

```
  def getLibraryVersion() {
            return module.hasProperty('libraryVersion') ? libraryVersion : "1.0.0"
        }
```

But its not picking up the correct value defined in the modules.

Any idea of what's going on??

Answer (score 0):

From your top build.gradle, put the code inside of a `subprojects { }` closure.

The project specific variables can be referenced in your global script with:

```
ext.MyProjectVar
```

And defined in each subproject:

```
ext.MyProjectVar = 'some value'
```